# Use of Bayes' Theorem to find false positive rate

Tags: probability, statistics, bayes-theorem

I have been asked to use Bayes' Theorem to prove that the rate of false positives is accurate (86%) in the following passage.

What I have done so far is list the following

$P(A)=0.99$

$P(B)=0.05$

As Bayes' Theorem is as follows

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$$

I need $P(B|A)$. I'm stuck on how to find this. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Is it possible to prove this using Bayes'? If not, is there some other sort of mathematics that I can use here?

> Roughly 1 per cent of the population suffer from mild cognitive
>   impairment, which might, but doesn’t always, lead to dementia. Suppose
>   that the test is quite a good one, in the sense that 95 per cent of
>   the time it gives the right (negative) answer for people who are free
>   of the condition. That means that 5 per cent of the people who don’t
>   have cognitive impairment will test, falsely, as positive. That
>   doesn’t sound bad. It’s directly analogous to tests of significance
>   which will give 5 per cent of false positives when there is no real
>   effect, if we use a p-value of less than 5 per cent to mean
>   ‘statistically significant’.
>
> But in fact the screening test is not good – it’s actually appallingly
>   bad, because 86 per cent, not 5 per cent, of all positive tests are
>   false positives. So only 14 per cent of positive tests are correct.
>   This happens because most people don’t have the condition, and so the
>   false positives from these people (5 per cent of 99 per cent of the
>   people), outweigh the number of true positives that arise from the
>   much smaller number of people who have the condition (80 per cent of 1
>   per cent of the people, if we assume 80 per cent of people with the
>   disease are detected successfully).

Thanks

Comment: See the [drug testing example](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem#Drug_testing) in the Wikipedia entry for Bayes’ theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event that a person randomly chosen doesn't suffer from cognitive impairment and $B$ be the result of the test for dementia which can either be positive $P$ or negative $N$. Then,

$P(A) = 0.99 = 1 - P(A^C)$

$P(B = N | A) = 0.95$

I also assume that $95\%$ is the accuracy of the test in the sense that if the patient has the disease then $95\%$ of the time the test is positive and if the patient does not suffer from the disease then also $95\%$ of the time the test is negative. So,

$P(B = P | A^C) = 0.95$ and $P(B = P | A) = 0.05$

So, the probability of false positive is,

$P(A|B=P) = \frac{P(B = P | A) P(A)}{P(B = P | A) P(A) + P(B = P | A^C) P(A^C)} 
 = \frac{0.05 \times 0.99}{0.05 \times 0.99 + 0.95 \times 0.01} = 0.838$